# How to add Value of DataTable to specific Dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, dataset

I have 2 DataTables with value that needs to be added to a DataSet:

DataTable for **FSIC**:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ControlNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add("Year");
        dt.Columns.Add("CRO");
        dt.Columns.Add("Assessor");
        dt.Columns.Add("DateIssued");
        dt.Columns.Add("AmountPaid");
        dt.Columns.Add("ORNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add("DatePaid");
        dt.Columns.Add("Remarks");

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { ControlNumber, Year, CRO, Assessor, DateIssued, AmountPaid, ORNumber, DatePaid});
```

DataTable for `GeneralInfo`:

```
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.Add("BIN");
        dt2.Columns.Add("NameOfEstablishment");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Owner");
        dt2.Columns.Add("BusinessAddress");
        dt2.Columns.Add("Barangay");
        dt2.Columns.Add("NatureOfBusiness");
        dt2.Columns.Add("ContactNumber");

        dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { BIN, NameOfEstablishment, Owner, BusinessAddress, Barangay, NatureOfBusiness, ContactNumber});
```

I want to put them In my DataSet(named **DataSet1.xsd**)
[image]

I tried `DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables["GeneralInfo"];`
and DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];

But still giving errors

Comment: dataSet.Tables.Add(someDataTable);

Comment: "But still giving errors" - what *exactly* did it say? Be explicit. Also, the number of occasions when `DataTable` is an appropriate tool for a problem is *very* small and niche, and the fact that you seem to know the table structure in advance here makes it highly likely that your scenario does not qualify. Virtually any other approach is preferable to `DataSet`/`DataTable`. Is there a reason for using it?

Comment: The code you tried is passing the data from DataSet to DataTable instead of saving the DataTable to the DataSet. And what the error did you get?